# C-Got incompatible types in assignment at if-else if part

Tags: c, compiler-errors, runtime-error, incompatibletypeerror

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct not{
int id,hw,mdt,fnl;
char name[20];
char lname[20];
        }rec;


int main(){
FILE *fp1,*fp2;
char a1[3]="A",a2[3]="B",a3[3]="C",a4[3]="D",a5[3]="F";
float numgrade;
char letgrade[3];
```

I got `inf.txt` file with 10 student's `ID`,`NAME`,`LAST NAME`,`HOMEWORK GRADE`,`MIDTERM` AND `FINAL GRADE`.

> ```
> fp1=fopen("inf.txt","r");
> fp2=fopen("outf.txt","w");
> ```

```
   while( !feof(fp1)){
fscanf(fp1,"%d %s %s %d %d %d\n",&rec.id,rec.name,rec.lname,&rec.hw,&rec.mdt,&rec.fnl);
numgrade = (0.15)*rec.hw + (0.35)*rec.mdt + (0.5)*rec.fnl;
```

I got incompatible types in assignment error at if-else if part

> ```
>  if(numgrade>=0 && numgrade <=40) letgrade=strcat(a5,a5);
>  else if(numgrade>=41 && numgrade<=45) letgrade=strcat(a4,a4);
>  else if(numgrade>=46 && numgrade<=52) letgrade=strcat(a4,a3);
>  else if(numgrade>=53 && numgrade<=60) letgrade=strcat(a3,a3);
>  else if(numgrade>=61 && numgrade<=69) letgrade=strcat(a3,a2);
>  else if(numgrade>=70 && numgrade<=79) letgrade=strcat(a2,a2);
>  else if(numgrade>=80 && numgrade<=89) letgrade=strcat(a2,a1);
>  else if(numgrade>=90) letgrade=strcat(a1,a1);
> ```

```
fprintf(fp2,"%d %-12s %-12s %3d %3s",rec.id,rec.name,rec.lname,numgrade,letgrade);

}
fclose(fp1);
fclose(fp2);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I searched incompatible types in assignment error in SOF but couldnt find something useful for my code.

Comment: You cannot assign to arrays.

Comment: If you know strcat, you should know strcpy too. It isn´t possible to assign strings with `=` (except in some initialization cases)

Comment: Change `char letgrade[3]` to `char * letgrade`.

Comment: `strcat(a4,a4);` causes undefined behaviour. The operands to `strcat` must not overlap. Even if your code appears to work, you should replace this with something that is well-defined.

Comment: `while(!feof(fp1))` is wrong. C is not Pascal. EOF is not detected until *after* a read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared

```
char letgrade[3];
```

as an array. In C, arrays cannot be assigned with `=` operator. Pointers can be assigned, but you would need to manage memory pointed to by the pointers.

If you would like to concatenate two strings into `letgrade`, use the following code:

```
strcpy(letgrade, a5); // Copy the first part
strcat(letgrade, a5); // Append the second part
```

Note that in order for the above code to work properly, the length of `a5` must not exceed `1`. Otherwise, `strcat` would write past the end of `letgrade`.

Comment: It solved my error , now i should find a way to stop the crash :) Thank you for your help!